Conditions for factors of diffeomorphic Cartesian products to be themselves diffeomorphic?
Setup: Let $M$ be a smooth $k$-dimensional embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (usual smooth structure). Suppose that $M \times \mathbb{R}^{n - k}$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Question: Under what conditions can we claim that $M$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{k}$?
In general it is not possible to cancel factors in diffeomorphic products.
An example is given here: Diffeomorphisms between factors in diffeomorphic product manifolds. However, in this post, they suggest that it is possible to obtain a homeomorphism between $M$ and $\mathbb{R}^k$ because $\mathbb{R}^{n - k}$ is a $T_1$ space. But there is no reference and I don't see how to prove it. If it is true, can we somehow extend the claim to a diffeomorphism?
There is also this post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26385/when-factors-may-be-cancelled-in-homeomorphic-products/26460. They provide examples of bad things that can happen. They mention the "Dogbone space". This is a space $M$ such that $M \times \mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$ but $M$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Is there a way to rule out these pathological situations?
Context: I have a smooth fiber bundle $\mathbb{R}^{n - k} \to \mathbb{R}^n \to M$. I know that $M$ is contractible, which implies that the bundle is trivial. This gives a diffeomorphism between $M \times \mathbb{R}^{n - k}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$. I want to further argue that $M$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Well, if you assume that it is homeomorphic to $R^k$ and $k\ne 4$. Do you know about Whitehead manifold and exotic $R^4$'s?

Here is what you should know:

The assumption that $M$ is a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$ is redundant, it follows from the second assumption, that $M\times \mathbb R^{n-k}$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$.

The unsupported claim made in the linked answer here ("it is possible to obtain a homeomorphism between $M$  and $\mathbb R^k$  because $\mathbb R^{n-k}$ is a $T1$ space") is utterly wrong. A simple counter-example is given by the following: Let $M_1$ be the once punctured 2-dimensional torus and $M_2$ be trice punctured 2-dimensional sphere. Then $M_1\times \mathbb R$ is diffeomorphic to $M_2\times \mathbb R$, but $M_1$ is not homeomorphic to $M_2$. More to the point (since you are interested in contractible manifolds), if $W$ is a contractible topological $k$-dimensional manifold, then $W\times \mathbb R$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^{k+1}$, while if $W$ is a contractible smooth manifold, then  $W\times \mathbb R$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^{k+1}$. A standard example  is the 3-dimensional Whitehead manifold $W$ (it is contractible but not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^3$). See the discussion and references in this Mathoverflow post.

There are no easy nontrivial sufficient conditions for a contractibe $k$-dimensional manifold $W$ to be diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^k$. One can break this in two subproblems:


a. $W$ might be homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic to   $\mathbb R^k$. This can happen if and only iff $k=4$. (A nontrivial theorem due to Stallings that for $k\ne 4$, a smooth manifold is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^k$ if and only if it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^k$. Existence of exotic smooth structures on $\mathbb R^4$ is also nontrivial and is due to Gompf).
b. $W$ need not be homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^k$. This cannot happen if $k\le 2$ but happens for all $k\ge 3$. The first example is due to Whitehead (the Whitehead manifold). It was proven by Stallings in all dimensions $\ne 4$ and by Freedman in dimension $4$ that the only obstruction to this, besides contractibility, is "nontrivial fundamental group at infinity."
Freedman, Michael Hartley, The topology of four-dimensional manifolds, J. Differ. Geom. 17, 357-453 (1982). ZBL0528.57011.
Stallings, J., The piecewise-linear structure of euclidean space, Proc. Camb. Philos. Soc. 58, 481-488 (1962). ZBL0107.40203.

Thanks for the very detailed answer. I imagine that the main issue is to get simple connectedness at infinity? It may be a naive question, but could it follow from the fiber bundle structure?

@Sap Just read what I wrote few more times. In short, it does not follow.

@MoisheKohan What if you additionally assume that $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is closed?  The Whitehead manifold $W \subset S^3 \subset \mathbb{R}^4$ is not closed.  Thanks in advance!

Well, based on this answer (of Moishe), it seems that $M$ being closed (or even a smooth real algebraic variety) is not enough: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1986451/example-of-contractible-open-manifold-that-is-not-mathbbrn-varieties

@ccriscitiello: In OP's question the manifold $M$ cannot be closed because it is contractible (which follows from the fact that $M\times R^{n-k}$ is homeomorphic to $R^n$.

@ccriscitiello: But maybe you do not mean a closed manifold, but rather a closed subset of $\mathbb R^n$. Then Whitehead manifold is also diffeomorphic to a closed subset of $\mathbb R^4$. In fact, if $N$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb R^m$, then $N$ is diffeomorphic to a closed subset f $\mathbb R^{m+1}$.

@MoisheKohan Got it, thanks once again!  Do you have a reference for that last fact ("In fact, if $N$ is a submanifold ...")?

@ccriscitiello I do not have a reference but it is an easy consequence of existence of a smooth proper function on a smooth manifold (the closed subset will be the graph of such function).

@MoisheKohan Thanks for the explanation!  Another question (hopefully the last!): in item 2 of your answer, you say that "if $W$ is a contractible $k$-dimensional smooth manifold then $W \times \mathbb{R}$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$."  Do you have a reference (or explanation) for this?

@ccriscitiello: It's complicated and is a combination of several different results. Did you read the linked MO discussion?

@MoisheKohan Got it, I'll take a close look at the references provided by Shijie Gu.  Thanks again!!
